# Contenteditable element background blinking on touch inside element

Tags: ios, css, html

How to avoid contenteditable div background blinking with gray color on touch inside div?
Can be reproduced on iOS Safari or UIWebview object.

Example HTML URL: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable
Example Image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-On7OzzI7SZZmtLMGEzZHNfNkU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this css to your div which is "contenteditable=true"

```
div {
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```